# Load multiple azure sql tables in to excel sheets

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to extract data from multiple azure sql tables and load into excel file spreadsheets in blob storage.Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy SQL tables to excel using below approach:

Connect Excel to a database in Azure SQL Database.

Click on Get Data. Select Database and Enter credentials.

Now Select database also you need to set firewall rules if you are exporting tables from Azure SQL database.

[image]

Refer - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/connect-excel